# Loading .txt files using a function in R

Tags: r, string, function

The following code works:

```
Name<-"s1521r0000_rd2.txt"  
OneFile<-read.table(file=Name, sep="", skip=35, fill=TRUE )
```

But, I am trying to write a function that will load one .txt file so that I can load whatever .txt file I want. I wrote the following function which is not working:

```
ReadOneFile<-function(Name="s1521r0000_rd2.txt"){  
 OneFile<-read.table(file=Name, sep="", skip=35, fill=TRUE )  
}
```

It would be great if you could help me.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `return(OneFile)` or just get rid of the `OneFile<-`, since the last value computed is the default return value.

Comment: Can I ask what you want to accomplish with this? You can easily do it with the code below, but you're basically wrapping an existing function in another function, which seems unnecessary?

Comment: Are you just trying to load all files in a directory at once in a loop and assign them names?

Comment: I'm guessing your mistake is thinking that `OneFile` will get modified when you just call `ReadOneFile(...)`, which it won't - variables inside function scope are local to that scope, so that `OneFile` inside the function is **different** from `OneFile` outside of it (you could assign to variables outside if you really wanted to, but don't, simply use return values)

Comment: @TARehman, I am planning to load one file and do some operations on it and load another and so on.

Comment: @vagabond, no I am not trying to load all file in a directory. The files are in different directory and I am loading a subset of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return()` the file from the function into an object. For instance:

```
func.readonefile <- function(Name) {
    thefile <- read.table(file=Name,sep="",skip=35,fill=TRUE)
    return(thefile)
}
a_file <- func.readonefile(Name="s1521r0000_rd2.txt")
```

Comment: that `return` statement doesn't change anything for the code that you posted; `a <- b` has the value of `a` after the assignment (i.e. `b`), the only thing that `return` adds is that the value is returned *visibly*

Comment: It is true that the last item is returned implicitly in the manner you describe. However, with read.table if you don't assign it to something the output is written to stdout and won't be returned AFAIK.

Comment: it doesn't matter what the right hand side function is - try it

Comment: In any case, the function still works correctly, right? And we are on the same page 're: scoping of the function (i.e. you need to assign the output of the function to an object in the global environment).

Comment: Yes, the function works correctly, but I don't think this answer is useful

Comment: Well. Make a better one? :)

Comment: OP is too unclear to answer IMO - I ventured a guess in the comments, they can elaborate if they like

Comment: Unless you have `return` and assign the output of the function to an object you won't read the file into the global environment. Basically you're reading it within the scope of the function, but it won't go outside of that function. You can use `<<-' to do a global assignment, but that's generally bad practice.

Comment: @TARehman, it is working the way I want now using your solution. Thanks for the help.